# How to perform insert and update bulk operation in Elastic search using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, .net-core

I am getting data from service broker queue using listener in ASP.NET Core project. Here I am getting around 10000 data. After getting, I am creating list of ElasticModel object data (Count 10000). The object contains an `EquipmentId` field using which I want to I want to update the existing `EquipmentId` data on Elastic index and insert if new data is came.

How can I do it in a bulk operation?

Comment: Are you using the sqlserver service broker?

Comment: @QiangFu , I am using SQL service broker